# Tests for a method that writes to a file in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, file-io

I have a method that writes to a file with a given name. Do I have to test this method and, if so, for what should I test it?

```
public void record(Object o){
    try{

        FileWriter fileStream = new FileWriter("data.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileStream);

        out.write(o.toString());
        out.newLine();  
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: In this particular case I would suggest to use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), and avoid low level unit testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you have to test is or not is a question for your project lead. If it's determined you should write some tests, then I would test at least these cases

- Happy path (write a good object, check the file contents afterwards)
- What happens with a null argument (file exist? what's in it? Does it get closed?)
- What happens if the method is called multiple times?
- What happens if the file already exists, but is not writeable

Comment: If the file does not exist for example it will be caught, or I need to test if the try catch really catches the exception?

Comment: You don't have to test whether the *language* works correctly -- i.e., you can assume that  `try` and `catch` work correctly. But you should test, for example, what state things are left in if there is a problem. For example, if the `toString()` method throws an exception, it'll be caught, and a message printed to standard output (which, by the way, is virtually *never* the right thing to do in real code.) But the file will still be open, and subsequent calls to this method will fail -- on the Windows OS, anyway -- for that reason. Those are the kinds of things that testing can discover.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question "Should I test this?" is always "YES". Now, you might not be able to, or might not know how to, or have the time to, or be allowed to, or want to, but that doesn't change the answer.

Comment: Very good point :D. I guess I am not sure for what to test it though

Comment: The other answers have excellent suggestions. I would only add that you should try their suggestions on as many platforms as you expect to run on.

Answer (score 2):

Tests are always welcome, but in this case thorough code review might be beneficial. It is hard to write a test that will discover that:

- `out` might not be closed properly, causing file descriptors to leak, i.e. when `o.toString()` throws an exception
- *if* it throws an exception, the stack trace will get lost (incorrect exception handling)
- how should the method behave if the `Object o` does not override `toString()` should it care?

Comment: Yeap, this is right. That's why I was really confused for what to test  here

Comment: @user1181847: well, it's not that bad. For instance you can test how does this method report I/O error (it does not...), you examine the file contents (is newline actually added), check file name, etc. But stricly speaking this is no longer *unit* -testing.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more code review suggestions: `out.close()` should be in a `finally` block (with its own try/catch), you might want to check the input parameter for sanity, you might want to check if the file already exists and is writable. Also, what happens if `o` is a `String` with its own newlines?